# Representation of a pow function in the form of a loop

Tags: c, loops, numbers, pow, nth-root

Hello I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

I made a program that calculates the nth root of a number. Here's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define EPS 1e-5
/*
*/
int main()
{
double xs,xn,n,x,degree=1,l;
printf("Enter n>0:");
scanf("%lf",&n);
while(n<1)
{
    printf("Enter n>0:");
    scanf("%lf",&n);
}
printf("Enter x:");
scanf("%lf",&x);
xn=(x+1)/n;

while(fabs(xn-xs)>EPS)
{
    xs=xn;
    l=pow(xs,n-1);
    xn=(1/n)*((n-1)*xs+(x/l));
}
printf("%lf",xn);
return 0;
}
```

I wanted to modify this program, ie. not to use the pow function.I wanted to use the loop for what the pow function was doing.
This is a modification code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define EPS 1e-5
 /*
 */
int main()
{
double xs,xn,n,x,degree=1;
printf("Enter n>0:");
scanf("%lf",&n);
while(n<1)
{
    printf("Enter n>0:");
    scanf("%lf",&n);
}
printf("Enter x:");
scanf("%lf",&x);
xn=(x+1)/n;

while(fabs(xn-xs)>EPS)
{
    xs=xn;
    for(int i=1;i<=(n-1);i++)
    {
        degree=degree*xs;
    }
    xn=(1/n)*((n-1)*xs+(x/degree));
}
printf("%lf",xn);

return 0;
}
```

But I do not get the same result in both codes, ie. in the first code I get the correct result, while in the second I don't.Also, I don't understand what the problem is in the second code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop that calculates the power sits inside another loop, so on the next iteration of the outer loop `degree` still has the same value it had prior.  You need to reset it before entering the inner loop:

```
degree=1;
for(int i=1;i<=(n-1);i++)
{
    degree=degree*xs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You saved me !